# how does socket.io client find /socket.io/socket.io.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have node, socket.io, npm installed on an ubuntu 16.04 aws instance.  I can start a socket.io project and it is running -- says listening on port *3000, but on the client side

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

cannot find the client file.

What service translates the src path into the real path, and where should npm and node_modules be installed relative to the client.html file?

Comment: I feel your question is a little bit off topic.  [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's automatically served by your http server with

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
```

Socket.IO also needs an HTTP server for polling, and upgrading connection from HTTP to websocket.